# Como comprimir imagens no PHP?

Tags: php

No meu site, pessoas podem postar mensagens e junto com essas mensagens uma imagem (que é salva em uma pasta). Gostaria de saber se existe alguma classe ou algum meio utilizando PHP de comprimir essas imagens sem perder a qualidade.

**Obs.: Extensões aceitas: .jpg e .png**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode testar a perda de qualidade usando o [`PHP GD`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.image.php) e ver se te atende, você também pode fazer esse procedimento enquanto estiver fazendo o upload da imagem:

```
function compressImage($source_path, $destination_path, $quality) {
    $info = getimagesize($source_path);

    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_path);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_path);
    }

    imagejpeg($image, $destination_path, $quality);

    return $destination_path;
}
```

Explicando as funções usadas:

- [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.getimagesize.php): retorna as informações da imagem (tipo, tamanho, dimensões, etc), usamos pra conseguir o MIME Type da imagem original.
- [`imagecreatefromjpeg()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php): cria uma nova imagem à partir da imagem original.
- [`imagejpeg()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagejpeg.php): envia uma imagem para o navegador ou para um arquivo, é aqui que a imagem mais leve é criada.

Por fim a função retorna o caminho da imagem mais leve.

**Exemplo de uso:** `$img = compressImage("images/praia.jpg", "images/compressed/compressed_praia.jpg", 6);`

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado por responder. Tenho uma dúvida, no caso, quando menor o valor de #quality meno o tamanho da imagem ou menos qualidade? Não entendi direito o que o código em si faz. Por exemplo, esse imagecreatefromjpeg criaria uma imagem mais "leve"?

Comment: Isso, quanto menor o valor de `$quality` pior será a sua qualidade, o padrão é +- 7.5. Editei a resposta com a explicação das funções utilizadas. A função `imagecreatefromjpeg /png` cria o identificador da imagem, e não a imagem em si, ela é realmente criada com a função `imagejpeg()`, é importante ressaltar que a imagem gerada será sempre com o formato `.jpeg`.

Comment: Obrigado por responder, @EduardoSilva, porém vou ficar com a alternativa do Imagick(); que no meu caso parece mais viável. Obrigado!

Comment: Gosto da solução por ela usar uma lib que normalmente já vem no PHP. A Image Magik pode até ter mais recursos, mas nenhum deles vai ajudar no problema em questão.

Comment: Será, @Bacco? Vou ver entre as duas e comento aqui qual foi melhor...

Comment: @Igor ambas servem para redimensionar imagens, e ambas tem um ajuste de qualidade ao salvar, por isso geralmente eu dou preferência para a GD nos meus projetos. Mas é bom você conhecer as duas, para quando precisar para outros usos.

Comment: É mesmo, realmente nesse caso o que me atende é o GD. Obrigado! :D

Comment: Para complementar a resposta do @EduardoSilva [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614925/remove-exif-data-from-jpg-using-php#answer-3615080) explica como remover os cabeçalhos EXIF da imagem com o GD.

Comment: E o que são esses cabeçalhos EXIF, @fernandosavio? Faz diferença retirá-los ou não?

Comment: [EXIF](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) são dados sobre a camêra e outros metadados que são interessante de guardar com a imagem original, mas para usar na web os otimizadores de imagens geralmente retiram eles da imagem para diminuir o tamanho da mesma.

Answer (score 3):

Existem várias bibliotecas de processamento de imagens, algumas que conheço são:

- [GD2](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)
- [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)

Aconselho a usar o [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) ([eis o motivo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023068/which-php-image-processing-library-is-more-powerful-imagick-or-gd)).

Algumas coisas que tu pode fazer para deixar suar imagens beeeem menores.

- [Converter a imagem para JPG](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageformat.php)
- [Utilizar uma qualidade](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setcompressionquality.php) entre 80 e 90 para o JPG
- [Redimensionar a imagem](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php) para um tamanho máximo. Ex.: 800px de largura
- [Eliminar os cabeçalhos EXIF](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.stripimage.php)

Fontes:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Exemplo:

```
<?php
    $image = new Imagick();

    $image->thumbnailImage(800, 300);
    $image->readImage('image.jpg');
    $image->setImageFormat('jpeg');
    $image->setImageCompressionQuality(85);
    $image->stripImage();

    $image->writeImage('nova_imagem.jpg');

?>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era exatamente o que eu precisava! Somente mais uma dúvida. No caso onde será salva essa nova imagem? E como faço com uma imagem que acabei de upar?

Comment: Já tinha sofrido com isso ano passado e consegui que as imagens saíssem muito pequenas (Imagens de 1100x700 com 150k ou menos).

Comment: essa função Imagick(); já é implementada no PHP ou tenho que fazer download de algum arquivo externo?

Comment: É um módulo do PHP que conecta com a biblioteca. No `phpinfo();` tu vê se ela está ativada. Senão estiver é só modificar no php.ini para que ela seja carregada.
Se não estiver no lá no php.ini provavelmente vai ter que instalar para o seu sistema operacional